# How to Automatically start Application

Tags: c#, network-programming, registry, exe

I work on C#.recently i work on **Tcp server-client** .I write a client **application** .want it's start automatically when client start os .Actually i have an exe,want it active when user start his computer.What i need to do?Thanks.if have any query plz ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways that you can make an application start at run time.

For a list of locations. [Check this article](http://www.tweaksforgeeks.com/WinStartupLoc.html)

To summarize they are

`Start->Programs->StartUp folder`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run`

Answer (score 2):

Add following code on your program first page....

```
    public string path;
    public string fileName;
    public void GetExeLocation()
    {
        path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location; // for getting the location of exe file ( it can change when you change the location of exe)
        fileName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name; // for getting the name of exe file( it can change when you change the name of exe)
        StartExeWhenPcStartup(fileName,path); // start the exe autometically when computer is stared.
    }

    public void StartExeWhenPcStartup(string filename,string filepath)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        key.SetValue(filename, filepath);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two options:

- Create a shortcut to your program in the Startup folder of your start menu
- Create an entry in the registry in the `Run` key

Comment: will you plz tell me how to add on registry.

Answer (score 0):

The Window Autostart Folder can be very useful. I normally put my applications there.

Answer (score 0):

Making your server a windows service is a better option. This way even if the no one is logged on to the computer your program will start and run.
Generally, services are a better choice for server applications requiring to run on OS startup.

You can read about how to create a service in C# in the following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx)